# QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded

Tags: linux, mysql, qt

I have a problem with Qt connecting with MySql, when i run this code

```c
    QSqlDatabase DBObject = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    DBObject.setHostName("localhost");
    DBObject.setDatabaseName("SingleDB");
    DBObject.setUserName("root");
    DBObject.setPassword("abc123");
    bool ok = DBObject.open();
```

I got this...
[QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJT0y.png)

I Have already done this also:
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient

and

```
/home/wrm/Qt/5.12.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/local/lib -lmysqlclient_r" mysql.pro
```

and here i have this error:
[Project ERROR: Library 'mysql' is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bDUc.png)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you get a "driver not loaded" error, the problem is the path where the libqsqlmysql.so is.

That library is contained in the plugins/sqldrivers folder of your Qt installation and that (sqldrivers) folder should be available to your executable.

You have to make sure that the sqldrivers folder is in the same folder of your executable (that is one of the default lookup paths) or change those paths within your code using [QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#addLibraryPath)

So, to sum it up:

1. be sure of the path of the sqldrivers folder (or change the plugin lookup path)
2. be sure to link against libmysqlclient as well (on my system libmysqlclient_r is just a link to libmysqlclient)
3. Try posting some small piece of code that does not work for you.